# TCPListener and TCPClient doesn't work when not connecting to localhost

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, tcp

I made a program that connects to a server (which I also wrote) via TCP\IP.

When testing on the same computer - it works fine (connect to 127.0.0.1), but it doesn't work on different computers.

I have an NOIP address also - how can I use it?

I did try using my address itself (80.whatever) on both the client and server and it didn't connect at all - it couldn't reach the host.

What should I do?

Comment: Have you checked the firewall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Try disabling your windows Firewall.
- Make sure your server is binding to all of your IP addresses, not just localhost (127.0.0.1).

Answer (score 1):

Oh - basically I found out that I don't need to supply my IP address - I just did:
`_client = new TcpListener(1234);`